# List all files with corrupt filenames recursively

Tags: bash, find, corruption, encoding, ascii

I've got a Linux server with some directories and files structure on it. Apparently somehow someone uploaded a bunch of filenames, which got corrupted. Consider the following example:

```
└── parent
    ├── foo1.jpg
    ├── f+�o2.jpg
    └── foo+�.html
```

There are about 1000 files and directories, so manual fixing is not really a good option. Is there a way to find all corrupted names with a single terminal command? Maybe a command, which filters the names which contain non-ascii symbols or something like that? What would be the best practice? Thank you!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/113188/75668

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are simply looking to identity filenames containing non-ASCII characters:

```
LC_ALL=C find /path/to/files | grep -P "[\x80-\xFF]"
```

If this does not work for you, I recommend you download and install `detox`.  From it's manpage:

> The detox utility renames files to make them easier to work with.  It removes spaces and other such annoyances.  It'll also translate or cleanup Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) characters encoded in 8-bit ASCII, Unicode characters encoded in UTF-8, and CGI escaped characters.